# Will ethereum.org re-send a presale json wallet if I lost my original and never moved the coins?

Tags: wallets, presale

Bought some ether in the presale, received a pdf receipt with my password, transaction id, and future ETH address, but I never did anything with it, never even looked at it again, until now.  I thought saving this info would allow me to repopulate a wallet in the future. Tried a bunch of things and they didnt work so Im wondering:

Can ethereum.org re-send the email containing my json wallet? If anyone has a clue how I can get access to my presale ether now it would be much appreciated since I bought several of them!

Comment: What address do you have?